# How do I make something more formal?

Tags: formal-language

How do I make this more formal? The part of the sentence: a lot of the times.

Comment: a lot of the time,for mostly, not usually a lot of the times, unless referring to specific times. You need to provide a sentence,not just the phrase.

Comment: more context is needed for this to be a clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Frequently" or "often" are used in both formal and informal English.

Comment: Often is the one I used for the essay.

Answer (score 2):

"Much of the time" / "Many of the times" are slightly more formal versions of "a lot of the time(s)", but still commonly used in everyday speech.

Answer (score -1):

> Quite often

is a formalized and concise version.